# How to call a function GroupBox as a parameter and use its controls?

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms.

Form1 has 3 checkboxes inside groupBox1.

Form2 has 1 listBox.

I want a function I can use in Form1 that if I call groupBox as a parameter, it would use all of its controls (3 checkboxes) to populate the listBox1.

I think I would need to use foreach, but I have no idea how I would approach this problem. Can someone give me a hint?

edit-----------------

Is this good?

```
public void Test(params GroupBox[] groupboxes)
{
    var checkBoxes = groupboxes.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

    foreach(var checkBox in checkBoxes)
    {
        if(checkBox.Checked==true)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checkBoxes = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
foreach (var checkBox in checkBoxes)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox.Text);
}
```